# How to override Parsley JS focus behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

When a new user comes to the page and types in an email that already exists in the system, I would like to do the following:

1. Show the error message.
2. Show the arrow.
3. Then move the focus(cursor)
   to the Password field.

Using jQuery I'm able to move the focus to the **password** field, but after a few milliseconds, the focus is pulled back to the **email** field with the Parsley error message.

I have tried using `data-parsley-focus="..."` and `data-parsley-no-focus`, but that didn't do anything for me. I've also looked at the source code and I see that `validate.focusedField.focus()` is what's forcing the focus back to the field with the error, but can't quite figure out how to stop that.

So, is there a way to override this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works as expected, although you might need to tweak some aspects based on your code.

What I did:

1. Whenever a field has an error, check if it's a specific field (*field1* in my case) and, if so, do something (in this case, focus on *field2* input).
2. Add [`data-parsley-focus="none"`](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-classes) to the form to avoid auto focus on the first input with errors (behaviour by default).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.listen('parsley:field:error', function(parsleyField) {
    if (parsleyField.$element.attr('name') === 'field1') {
      $("input[name=field2]").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.0.7/parsley.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" data-parsley-validate data-parsley-focus="none">
  <input type="text" name="field1" required data-parsley-minlength="50" data-parsley-trigger="focusout" />
  <input type="text" name="field2" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you run into some trouble, please provide a fiddle and add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I tried it out (https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/4e6r28o4/3/) and found that it does work, however when I go back to the previous field and start typing it keeps triggering .focus() without even focusing out or submitting the change.

Comment: I made some additional changes to your code and was able to get it to the point that I wanted (https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/4e6r28o4/4/). Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Since it does override the default Parsley focus behavior, this answer does fit my question. Thanks!

Comment: @GeneParcellano Nice one! I'm glad you got that working.